# Google Auth in Ionic app

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3

I'm implementing Google Authentication as described here:  https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in, in my Ionic 3 (Angular 4) app.

How can I execute an Angular method after the sign in.
Normally the javascript function onSignIn() is called. But I need to set Angular variables in that function (this.user) so it needs to be an angular function...

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i use this google plus plugin for google login in ionic:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-plus/

```
this.googlePlus.login({}).then(res => console.log(res))
```

in the event handler you can execute code after the login